# Strip Math ML (Convert to plain text)

Tags: mathml

I am working on a project that imports technical documents into a tracking system. A small number of the publications contain embedded `HTML`. This is normal and we strip out the `HTML` which is typically used to add formatting such as bold or italics to body text.

Now we are receiving documents containing `MathML`. Are there any libraries (or approaches) out there that will strip the markup and give a reasonable text equivalent? I realize that that `MathML` allows for graphical representations, but even those have text equivalents.

Comment: Do you just want to blow away the markup, or do you instead want to convert the markup from mathml to something else, say LaTeX? After all Mathml is already a text format.

Comment: I realize that if I want to just blow it away, I can likely do that with some type of regex processing. I wonder about converting / parsing / processing it to produce a pure text representation or something very close. Ideally in the end, I wind up with a text representation such as `(a + b + c) / (2  * 5)` (example).

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: @DavidLeBauer nope. That project was a while ago and I don't remember my exact solution but if memory serves me correctly it was pretty much to leave the MathML as is. A solution would have been nice to have but in the end not required. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would have to process the MathML and interpret it. Unlike in the case of removing html markup, stripping the tags would normally strip the meaning from the formula.

So you will need a mathml parser. Two do come to mind, both by David Carlisle, and both xslt based: pmml2tex converts to Latex format, which is often more or less readable: your example would be rendered as `\frac{a+b+c}{2\times 5}`

Alternatively pmathmlascii does little ascii art representations of mathml. Your example would render as

```
a + b + c
---------
  2 * 5
```

or similar.

Both stylesheets can be found on google code, and are discussed at https://code.google.com/p/web-xslt/wiki/Overview